# Adding second x_axis writes over title

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

How can I move the title of my subplot such that the second axis do not write on **top** of the title, but instead below it? Here's what it looks like

[image]

And here is the relavent snippet of code:

```
    # fig is a subplotAxes object
    fig.set_ylabel('Altitude (km)')
    fig.set_xlabel('Time')   
    fig.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))

    cbar_label = 'Total Attenuated Backscatter 532nm (km$^{-1}$ sr$^{-1}$)'
    cbar = pfig.colorbar(im)
    cbar.set_label(cbar_label)

    # create second axis
    ax2 = fig.twiny()
    ax2.set_label('Latitude')
    ax2.set_xlim(latitude[0], latitude[-1])

    # set title, but title is overwritten
    fig.set_title("Averaged 532 nm Total Attenuated Backscatter")
```

I don't know if this could be the cause of my figure size or a simple formatting error. I'd like to not have to expand my figure size as this plot lives inside a Tkinter window

Comment: Cool graph. What's it of?

Comment: @BetaDecay I'm writing some software for tracking harmful aerosols in the earths atmosphere! [webpage](http://syntaf.github.io/vocal/overview.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your title applies to the whole figure rather than just the subplot, @György Solymosi's answer is probably the way to go (rather than adding a new line, which is kind of a hack).

Alternatively, you could reposition the title text to wherever you want it, e.g. raising it up by 5%:

```
title = fig.set_title("Flying monkey density")
title_xy = title.get_position()
title.set_position([title_xy[0], title_xy[1]*1.05])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `fig.suptitle("Averaged 532 nm Total Attenuated Backscatter")`

Answer (score 1):

This solution was **way** simpler than I ever imagined, I feel dumb. All I needed to do was add a `\n` to the end of the title

```
 fig.set_title("Averaged 532 nm Total Attenuated Backscatter\n")
```

[image]